# Fetching data from webservice containing '&' does not give correct results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am fetching this string "Rasberry & Banana Smoothies" from web-service, it is getting the string as three different values instead of a single one:

Rasberry
&
Banana Smoothies

And if I remove the `&` symbol from server database, it fetches the complete string as it is.

I am not getting the reason why is this so, can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Here I am posting the code of fetching it, this might help to understand the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

arrayTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrayRecipe = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2-right-side-sheet-1.png"]];

NSString *url=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://smoktec.net/Monty/api/?"];

NSString *Action=@"action=";

NSString *compUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",url,Action,@"Recipes"];

NSURL *urlToPars= [NSURL URLWithString:compUrl];
NSLog(@"%@",compUrl);

[self parseWithUrl3:urlToPars];
}

-(void)parseWithUrl3:(NSURL *)compUrl
{
    parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:compUrl];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    stcurrentelement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",elementName];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if(!(stcurrentelement==nil))
    {
        if([stcurrentelement isEqualToString:@"Recipetitle"])
        {
            [arrayTitle addObject:string];
            NSLog(@"%@",string);
        }

        else if([stcurrentelement isEqualToString:@"RecipeImg"])
        {
            [arrayImage addObject:string];
            NSLog(@"%@",string);
        }

        else if([stcurrentelement isEqualToString:@"Recipeid"])
        {
            [arrayRecipe addObject:string];
            NSLog(@"%@",string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *compUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",url,Action,@"Recipes"];
NSString *URLEncodedText = [compURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You need to encode the URL string before making the request.

Comment: it does not put any effect, what it is for?

Comment: This is not the solution for this, it leaves the reserved characters (like slash / and ampersand &.

Comment: It adds percent encoding for special characters. '&' is %26 in URL encoding standards. If it is not working then probably try encoding NSString *url as well before passing it as a parameter to compURL.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the web service result/response and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution, concatenate the strings after recieving the data from server.

```
NSString *str = [arrayTitle objectAtIndex:3];
NSString *str1 = [arrayTitle objectAtIndex:4];
NSString *str2 = [arrayTitle objectAtIndex:5];

NSString *strring = [str stringByAppendingString:str1];
 NSString *strring1 = [strring stringByAppendingString:str2];

NSLog(@"strr:%@",strring1);
```